# Naming Conflict in Laravel 5 Database Seeding

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel-5, laravel-seeding

i am running into a naming conflict when running my database seeds (along with other console commands).

all of my models are stored in the `app/Models` directory, and are in the `App\Models` namespace. there is a base model in this directory called `Model.php` that extends the laravel base model.

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

abstract class Model extends BaseModel {}
```

some of my models extend this base class, for example

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

class User extends Model {}
```

some of my models extend the eloquent model directly, for example

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sport extends Model {}
```

this works fine when my application is accessed over http, and there are no naming conflicts.  however, when i try to run a console command, such as `db:seed`, I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Model because the name is already in use in /home/vagrant/Code/wisletics/app/Models/Sport.php on line 3
```

my initial guess is that laravel compiles the seed files somehow, which is causing the conflict. does anyone have any ideas, or has anyone else run into this issue already?

Comment: The compiled file can be found in storage directory `storage/framework/compiled.php`

Comment: I just had a thought - can you post your Database Seeder file please?

Comment: @satrun77 I am not seeing that file at all.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is at

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sport extends Model {}
```

This create a problem as you already has `App\Models\Model`, now when PHP try to get the parent class of `Sport` (`Model`), it can't decide whether you actually asking for `App\Models\Model` or `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.

This problem can be solved by actually changing it to:

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as BaseModel;

class Sport extends BaseModel {}
```

**Update**: Why are you seeing this while seeding? Well Laravel 5 uses PSR-4, it doesn't load any of your Model until it is requested, which is happening when you tried to run `SportTableSeeder`.

Comment: i believe you are correct with this answer, but any thoughts as to why it only causes an error when accessed in the console, and not over HTTP? i feel like it should fail both ways.

Comment: It could be due to this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66773

OpCache is normally disabled in CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I had a quick play around with this. I think you are right, the seed seems to group it all together, and that is giving you the naming conflict.

But I would like to add that I think your naming convention is a bit confusing. Using `Model` in different contexts within the same type of Eloquent classes does not seem ideal.

Why not just rename your `Model` as `BaseModel` - and leave the Eloquent class as `Model`. Then it is immediately obvious to someone glancing at your code how it functions.

**Edit:** So the issue is that the `DatabaseSeeder` class uses `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. It then does `$this->call('Your Seed File Here')` - which dynamically resolves and calls the class within itself - meaning that the other classes are run within the context of the `DatabaseSeeder` class.

This is creating the namespace issue - causing your seeds to fail.

You might be able to do this instead:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        $sport = new SportTableSeeder;
        $sport->run();    
    }
}
```

Note - you'll lose the seed output on the console with this method

Comment: isn't that the point of the `use`? I'm not overly concerned about the naming convention. laravel use to use a `BaseController`, but in the L5 upgrade it was renamed to `Controller`, and it imports the `Illuminate\Routing\Controller` as `BaseController`, so my naming is in line with that.

Comment: so I thought this as well, so I aliased my `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` in the database seeder, thinking this would resolve the issue, but no luck. your new suggestion is interesting, but as you said I lose the output, and also write 2x as many lines of code.